# What King Arthur adaptations depict the story of Uther Pendragon and Igrayne?

Tags: book-adaptation

Thomas Malory's book [*Le Morte D'Arthur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Morte_d%27Arthur), which is the definitive account of King Arthur's life, starts off with the story of how King Arthur's father Uther Pendragon desires Igrayne, the wife of the Duke of Cornwall.  So Uther invites the Duke and his wife to his castle, but they soon realize Uther's intentions and escape in the middle of the night.  This greatly angers Uther, who lies siege to the castle of the Duke of Cornwall.  In the course of the ensuing battle the Duke of Cornwall is killed, but then with the help of the wizard Merlin, Uther disguises himself as the Duke of Cornwall and fathers a child with Igrayne.  That child is Arthur, who is raised by a knight named Sir Ector but goes onto become the king of England after the death of Uther.

My question is, what TV and movie adaptations of King Arthur depict this story of Uther Pendragon disguising himself as the Duke of Cornwall and fathering a child with Igrayne?

The only ones I know of are the 1981 movie [*Excalibur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excalibur_(film)), the 1998 miniseries [*Merlin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(miniseries)), and the 2001 miniseries [*The Mists of Avalon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mists_of_Avalon_(miniseries)).  Are there any others?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but if you look through the [Help Center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help), specifically the [Asking page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), there are a couple issues here: For one, there's no way to definitively answer; you're asking for a list of titles, and putting together a complete list would be difficult ... and a new movie could come out tomorrow that should be added - that's why list questions are frowned upon on StackExchange sites. Also, you provide a partial answer in your question, which is also against recommendations.